# How to read the result of cv2.findContours?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I have a binary 2D-matrix `b` with shape `(340,490)` and apply `cv2.findContours(b,1,2)` on it. The result is a 3D array with shape `(6, 2, 1)` like `[[90,3],[5,60],[90, 110],[5,135],[3,200],[3,3]]`. I can't read it. I applied `cv2.drawContours(b,contours, -1, (0,0,255), 3)` It worked prefected. Since I have bunch of noisy on the original b. I don't know why it could be fixed only by 12 number. what does these number stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv2.drawContours()` function returns 2 values:

The first one in "Contours" and the second one is "Hierarchy".

Contours contain the coordinates of boundary points of each contour detected in the image.

To find number of contours, use:

```
len(Contours)
```

This will give the number of contours found in the image.

Now each element in the "Contours" will be of the following type:

```
Contours[i] = [[[x1, y1]],
               [[x2, y2]],
               [[x3, y3]],
               [[x4, y4]],
               [[x5, y5]],
               ...
               [[xn, yn]]]
```

where x and y are the coordinates of the boundary point of that contour in the image and n is the total number of boundary points of that contour.

To know about return value "Hierarchy", [refer to this link](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_hierarchy/py_contours_hierarchy.html).

Comment: Caveat: each element in `Contours[i]` returns a 3D NumPy array with a singleton dimension in the middle, so you actually get a `N x 1 x 2` NumPy array per contour.  This is evident from the way you formatted the layout of `Contours[i]`.  You are probably aware of this but it is not explicitly said in your answer, and it should be to be absolutely clear.

Comment: @rayryeng thanks for your comment, I forgot to mention that part in my answer.

Comment: Also, I don't know why the singleton dimension is added in between? Do reply if someone knows the reason behind this.

Comment: It's by design to make broadcasting easier when interfacing between NumPy and the OpenCV libraries in C++.